# Where is $(USERPROFILE)\appdata under ms visual studio ?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

So I was trying to change global settings for VC++ and was following this instruction (See #3)
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/03/02/visual-studio-2010-c-project-upgrade-guide.aspx.
Apparently I should have $(USERPROFILE)\appdata\local\microsoft\msbuild\v4.0 directory.
However I have nothing under my $(USERPROFILE). I have checked if I am looking under the right $USERPROFILE in cmd window. What have I possibily done/not done during my installation of ms visual studio 2012? Thank you

Comment: +1 Your question helped me to find that `$(userprofile)` is the currently logged user in the PC, thanks.